# Amazon MWS - getting product shipping costs

Tags: amazon-mws

For some skus I have to set specific shipping costs (or restrict shipping).

I use the following code/XML:

I tried this with MWS Scratchpad (https://mws.amazonservices.de/scratchpad/index.html)
Result = OK/Success/Done..., seems to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
       <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
       <MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Override</MessageType>
    <Message>
       <MessageID>1</MessageID>
       <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
       <Override>
           <SKU>2224</SKU>
           <ShippingOverride>
               <ShipOption>Std DE Europe 5</ShipOption>
               <Type>Additive</Type>
               <ShipAmount currency="EUR">999.00</ShipAmount>
           </ShippingOverride>
       </Override>
    </Message>
```

Want I'm looking for is a way to get this information back from amazon. Sku specific shipping costs or "isRestricted" value.

Is there any API method or can I get this data from a report ?

Any help ist appreciated. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetMyPriceForSKU` / `GetMyPriceForASIN` calls should return both the product price and shipping costs for your product. As stated in the [MWS Products API Reference](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/MWSProductsApiReference._V370495889_.pdf), page 41:

**BuyingPrice** - Contains pricing information that includes promotions and contains the
shipping cost.

Contains the following elements:

- **ListingPrice** – The current price including any promotions that apply to the product.
- **Shipping** – The shipping cost of the product. *<--This should include your override info*
- **LandedPrice** – ListingPrice plus Shipping.

If you really need to get that information as part of a report, please check if the `_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_` and `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_` include that information.

Comment: But which shipping costs are returned ? I think the shipping costs depend on the destination (<ShipOption>). When setting special shipping costs for a product and destination (as in the example above, special shipping costs for 2224 to "Std DE Europe 5" = 999 EUR), how to retrieve this data from MWS ? I can't find any option for GetMyPriceForXXX call to define the destination/shipOption.

Comment: What I'm searching for is a way to get "Override" data set by previous "_POST_PRODUCT_OVERRIDES_DATA_" feeds/calls (shipping costs and restricted flag).

Comment: @nrx I haven't worked with destination specific shipping overrides, so I don't know what GetMyPriceFor... calls would return. If you discover which API call returns your info, please answer your own question (or add another comment) here for future visitors. If there is none, please discuss with Amazon staff and also add that piece of informateion here for future reference

Comment: There is no API that would allow you to see the shipping costs of your products or a single listings. 

If you choose to use shipping overrides you would need to keep track of the changes you make yourself. 

If you are uncertain if or what override was used for a given listing you can upload the desired shipping override again. 

Thank you for selling with Amazon. 

Amazon.co.uk Seller Support